# How to overcome this memory issue in symfony 1.0.6?

Tags: apache, memory-management, symfony1, error-logging, php

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and getting this kind of error in /var/log/phpError.log

```
[27-Apr-2012 10:09:22] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in    Unknown on line 0
```

some times I also get

```
[27-Apr-2012 10:09:21] PHP Warning:  include() [<a      href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in /home/project/e4s-v1/lib/symfony/symfony.php on line 95
```

and

also `[27-Apr-2012 10:09:21] PHP Warning:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in /home/project/e4s-v1/lib/symfony/util/sfCore.class.php on line 163`

How to solve this...?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p ?