# How to de-fragment APC cache

Tags: php, caching, apc

Is it possible to de-fragment a APC cache or the only available option is to clear and rebuild it?
If we can't de-fragment it, is it a good idea to dump an entire cache clear it and then reload the dump? will this clear the fragmentation?

Comment: [What is your operating system?](http://geekblog.oneandoneis2.org/index.php/2006/08/17/why_doesn_t_linux_need_defragmenting)

Comment: @hakre, The problem is fragmentation reduces the number of stored files. currently I have around 12M/64M free space, totally fragmented, and the cache full count is at 12 in just 2 days. the stored files count had reduced to 360 from 510+. so i thought, it would be good if i can de-fragment the space at some interval.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

APC store opcodes in ram. It has no fragmentation management.

The only way to deframent is to flush cache.
Use apc_clear_cache() in php script.
Or restart httpd.

Note that APC will have to rebuild its cache.

There should be no (or few) fragmentation if you give APC enough memory.
Check my answer here to see how to guess the required ram
[What is causing "Unable to allocate memory for pool" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The accepted answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative way. If you install somewhere file called [apc.php](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/apc.php) with password (very important!) you can login on that site and flush opcode and user caches from there.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: @peter Yes it is one of the options. But its a manual process automation is always preferred.

Answer (score -1):

On Debian 8, install APC:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5-apcu
```

Then copy `apc.php` into your web root:

```
cp /usr/share/doc/php5-apcu/apc.php /var/www/html
```

Edit the file, modifying the `ADMIN_USERNAME` & `ADMIN_PASSWORD`.

Then visit the `apc.php` file in your browser, login, & hit `Clear Cache`.