# PHP: APC enabled, but still doesn't work?

Tags: php, apc

On my new Xubuntubox I installed the `lamp-server` tools, `php`, `php-apc`, added the `extension=apc.so` line to the php.ini and rebootet the system. Apache and PHP seem to work well, but APC doesn't.

So I checked what the apc.php file would say:

```
No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.
```

But in the php info it seems to be enabled. Have a look what `php -i | grep 'apc'` says:

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini,
apc
apc.cache_by_default => On => On
apc.canonicalize => On => On
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On             <- it is enabled
apc.file_md5 => Off => Off
apc.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
apc.filters => no value => no value
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.include_once_override => Off => Off
apc.lazy_classes => Off => Off
apc.lazy_functions => Off => Off
apc.max_file_size => 1M => 1M
apc.mmap_file_mask => no value => no value
apc.num_files_hint => 1000 => 1000
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.report_autofilter => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => default => default
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.stat => On => On
apc.stat_ctime => Off => Off
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.user_entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.user_ttl => 0 => 0
apc.write_lock => On => On
```

As expected `php -m | grep 'apc'` also finds `apc`.

Do you know what is missing, that I can't use it correctly?

Comment: Make sure you gave APC enough ram, 32M is very low (just enough fo one Wordpress site). Check my answer there to know how to configure APC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are **two** ways to run PHP.

You are showing the CLI configuration for PHP, and apc.php is not using it.

Indeed, if you check `phpinfo()` through your browser, you can see that no APC extension is loaded.

**The solution :** Open at `/etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/apc.ini` (`cgi` not `cli`) and paste your configuration there, again. Restart the web server (`sudo service httpd restart`) and voilà !

Hope this helps !

Comment: ah, okay. I thought that the automatically generated `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/apc.ini` would be enough. With the `.../cgi/...` folder it works with apache, now. The funny thing is that cli still doesn't work.

Comment: okay, for cli I just need to add another line to the `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini` that says `apc.enable_cli=1`

Comment: My server also says APC enabled but find / -name apc.ini does not show that I have a apc.ini file anywhere.

Comment: For PHP 5.5 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65731 "APC doesn't support PHP 5.5. PHP 5.5 comes bundled with an opcode cache now."