# APC restarts sometimes

Tags: php, apc

After installing APC, see the apc.php script, the uptime restart every one or two hours? why?
How can I change that?

I set `apc.gc_ttl = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today, found the solution here:
http://www.itofy.com/linux/cpanel/apc-cache-reset-every-2-hours/

You need to go to `AccesWHM > Apache Configuration > Piped Log Configuration` and `Enable Piped Apache Logs`.

Answer (score 1):

APC caches lives as long as their hosting process, it could be that your apache workers reach their [MaxConnectionsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#MaxConnectionsPerChild) limit and they get killed and respawned clearing the cache with it. This a safety mechanism against leaking processes.

- **mod_php**: [MaxConnectionsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#MaxConnectionsPerChild)
- **mod_fcgid or other fastcgi**: [FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestsperprocess) and [PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.lighttpd-14.php#install.unix.lighttpd-14.spawn-php) (enviroment variable, the example is for lighttpd but it should be considered everywhere `php -b` used)
- **php-fpm**: [pm.max_requests](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm.max-requests) individually for every pool.

You could try setting the option you are using to it's "doesn't matter" value (usually `0`) and run test the setup with a simple hello world php script, and apachebench `ab2 -n 10000 -c 10 http://localhost/hello.php` (tweak the values as needed) to see if the worker pid's are changing or not.

Comment: whit MaxConnectionsPerChild = 0 , same behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you use a TTL of 0 APC will clear all cache slots when it runs out of memory. This is what appends every 2 hours.

TTL must never be set to 0

Just read the manual to understand how TTL is used : http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.ttl

Use apc.php from http://pecl.php.net/get/APC, copy it to your webserver to check memory usage.

You must allow enough memory so APC have 20% free after some hours running. Check this on a regular basis.
If you don't have enough memory available, use filters option to prevent rarely accessed files from being cached.

Check my answer there
[What is causing "Unable to allocate memory for pool" in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p)