# require_once: cannot allocate memory

Tags: memory-management, php

I have a pretty "unconventional" setup that looks like this:

I have a VMware virtual machine running Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 with networking set to bridge. Installed inside the VM is nginx, php-fpm, php-cli and MySQL. PHP is 5.4.10.

I have a folder containing all the files for the application I am working on in the host (Windows 7). This folder is then made available as a network share.

The virtual machine then mounts the windows share via samba into a directory. This directory is then served by nginx and php-fpm. So far, everything has worked fine.

I have a script that I run via the php CLI to help me build and process some files. Previously, this script has worked fine on my windows host. However, it seems to throw `cannot allocate memory` errors when I run it in the Ubuntu VM. The weird thing is that it's sporadic as well and does not happen all the time.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo /usr/local/php/bin/php -f /www/app/process.php 

Warning: require_once(/www/app/somecomponent.php): failed to open stream: Cannot allocate memory in /www/app/loader.php on line 130

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/www/app/somecomponent.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php/lib/php') in /www/app/loader.php on line 130
```

I have checked and confirmed the following:

- `/www/app/somecomponent.php` definitely exists.
- The permissions for `/www` and all files and sub directories inside are set to execute and read+write for owner, group and others.
- I have turned off APC after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p) to see if APC is the cause, but the problem still persists after doing so.
- `php-cli` is using the same `php.ini` as `php-fpm`, which is located in `/etc/php/php.ini`.
- `memory_limit` in `php.ini` is set to `128M` (default) which seems plenty for the app.
- Even after increasing the memory limit to `256M`, the error still occurs.
- The VM has 2GB of memory.

I have been googling to find out what causes `cannot allocate memory` errors, but have found nothing useful. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: How much memory does your VM itself have, though?

Comment: The VM has 2GB of memory.

Comment: Is anything else running taking up an excessive amount of memory?

Comment: Not from what I can see. The swap isn't even being used because there is more than enough memory for all running processes.

Comment: Does it do anything before requiring `somecomponent.php`?

Comment: Yes it does, but those things don't seem to throw up any errors. The script is pretty complex and uses the autoloader (`loader.php`) to load classes.

Comment: Well, they may not throw up any errors themselves, but maybe they very nearly exhaust the existing memory? I’m not sure :P

Comment: Not very likely it would be hitting memory limits though (because it happens when I increase the `memory_limit` to `256M`. Having said that, sometimes, instead of throwing on the `require_once`, it throws the same `cannot allocate memory error` on a `file_get_contents` to load a 10kb JS file. I have a feeling that perhaps being a network share, something is making the files locked or unreadable occasionally.

Comment: Oh, and the strange thing is that `php-fpm` is totally fine. It only occurs when running scripts via `php-cli`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem with my windows share. Perhaps because Windows 7 is a client OS, it is not tuned to serve large amounts of files frequently (which is happening in my case).

To fix, set the following keys in the registry:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\LargeSystemCache` to `1`

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\Size` to `3`

I have been running my setup with these new settings for about a week and have not encountered any memory allocation errors since making the change.