# Drupal error "Unable to allocate memory for pool"

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I get this error with my Drupal site:

> Warning: Unknown: Unable to allocate memory for pool. in Unknown on
>   line 0

I have observed a similar post for [Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-p)  but not sure if it applies for Drupal. Can any one explain what should I do. I am using Drupal `6.27` and PHP `5.2.17`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an APC configuration issue. [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is an opcode cache for PHP

Search for APC settings in your php.ini or maybe in an apc.ini linked to your php.ini.

Possible solution is playing with these:
decrease apc.ttl and increase apc.shm_size

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the error will still occur even if you try yo override the settings with ini_set(). In this case you can also disable is entirely. For low traffic sites this will not be an issue.

Add this line to the top of your index.php file:

ini_set('apc.cache_by_default',0);

Answer (score 0):

Your Drupal site runs on the PHP programming language. You can configure the version of PHP used by your website.

The latest version of PHP 5.5. Uses OPcache opcode cache, and includes the APCu extension for 100% compatibility with the APC user caching API.

I upgrade the version from PHP 5.3 To PHP 5.5 and this worked for me.