# WordPress and APC's 'Unable to allocate memory for pool"

Tags: php, wordpress, apc

I have a typical cPanel server running the usuals where I'm running about ~20 small WordPress sites. Each site has W3TC installed and configured with the recommended settings. The server has 2GB of RAM.

Now, every so often, I'll run across the 'Unable to allocate memory pool' error. I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/what-is-causing-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool-in-php) particular question and its answer, in detail, many a times. I've tried what was suggested there, but it hasn't helped, so I was hoping to get some answers for my case.

The APC shmsize is currently set to 256M right now. APC.ttl is 120 and APC.gc_ttl is 3600.

Why am I still seeing errors? Is it recommended that I increase the shmsize even more? Or I'm missing something else here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember to restart your WEB server (apache, php-fpm or other) after make changes to the config.
2. Id the error is still there, you can add more memory yet (try 400M or even more), 20 small sites, probably has a tones of files to store in cache. Remember that your server is limited to 2GB of memory.
3. Also you could change gc_ttl to 1800 (it will decrease the store time, but will help you if you have small traffic on each of your sites)
4. If you still have a problem, you should configure the apc status page, and invistigate the APC use in your server. This article could help you: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-php-warning-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool/

Answer (score 0):

Change you apc.ini settings like below

```
apc.mmap_file_mask=/dev/zero
apc.shm_size=64M
apc.ttl=0
```

it works

Refer [apc.configuration.php](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php)