# APC doesn't respect PHP's Display error Off

Tags: php, apc

I was getting tons of **Warnings** in my production site. like

`PHP: Require_once(): Unable To Allocate Memory For Pool`

I know its caused by **APC** and after I increased the `shm_size` and decreased the `gc_ttl` its gone. but my query is how come it displayed that warning in the web page? I have disabled `display PHP errors` and Just log it and it doesn't display any PHP errors in website.

To test this, I deliberately created a script which would throw PHP Warning and Notices, and yes up to my satisfaction these are just logged, NOT Displayed like APC error.

So, how do I disabled APC Warnings in Production site? (in case if it happens again)

Comment: try setting it via php.ini . If you restart your httpd, the problem might be gone anyway.. :)

Comment: try what setting exactly? in php.ini `display_errors = Off` already

Comment: I did some research and it seems that this can't be turned off via php.ini. I can't find a setting to turn off error, in apc.ini either. So, I guess you should fix it ^_^  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3723338/1437261

Comment: Good question by the way. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit `apc.ini` not `php.ini` in `conf.d` directory. Checkout php.ini where is apc.ini used using phpinfo().

Check out is that exists and correct mask in directory (mask is "XXXXX"):

> apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX

Increase a memory to:

> apc.shm_size=96M

Set memory time to live settings:

> apc.ttl=3600

And temporary cache increase:

> apc.gc_ttl=3600

Reload your apache/nginx.

After that you need to find memory usage and set apc.ttl and apc.shm_size. Copy `/usr/share/php-pecl-apc/apc.php` to our www project and run via browser apc.php.

Edit apc.php administrator password in apc.php:

> defaults('ADMIN_PASSWORD','type-here-admin-password');

Save and run via browser. Then find `Hits` in `File cache information` to cheeck is used almost memory.

Reduce ttl value from above so you don't got memory error.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to respond, but your answer doesn't really satisfy my question. I know if I set `apc.ttl=0` then I will never get that memory error as `apc` will always reload the cache, but that's not effective way. I want `apc` to **work under the hood** and log the error/warnings/notices instead of displaying it.

Comment: You should never set `apc.ttl=0` because APC will flush all cache when it's out of memory. Make your script of APC to check is 30% free available of APC memory every 1 hour. If you don't have memory change apc cache using script. Look at this line https://github.com/khoaofgod/phpfastcache/blob/Stable-Version-1.x/phpfastcache_v1.3_stable/php_fast_cache.php#L1190 and set you time limit for APC store. Did you set up this?