# php5-fpm -t Unable to allocate shared memory segment

Tags: nginx, php

today i tried to setup my vserver with nginx and php5-fpm

but i somehow cannot get php5-fpm to work.

a `service php5-fpm start` looks like :

```
$ service php5-fpm start
php5-fpm start/running, process 27153
```

but nothing gets started. .pid doesnt get created aswell nor the .sock:

```
$ l /var/run/
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x 19 root          root        640 Sep  8 12:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root          root       4.0K Sep  8 12:43 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root         40 Sep  1 14:14 apache2
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi         avahi        80 Aug 11 11:12 avahi-daemon
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          7 Aug 10 11:50 container_type
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          4 Aug 10 11:50 crond.pid
----------  1 root          root          0 Aug 10 11:50 crond.reboot
drwxr-xr-x  2 messagebus    messagebus   80 Aug 11 11:12 dbus
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          0 Aug 10 11:53 init.upgraded
drwxrwxrwt  3 root          root         80 Aug 10 11:52 lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root        114 Sep  8 12:16 motd.dynamic
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root         60 Aug 10 11:50 mount
drwxr-xr-x  2 mumble-server adm          40 Sep  1 15:06 mumble-server
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql         root         80 Sep  1 14:21 mysqld
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root        160 Aug 10 11:51 network
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          6 Sep  8 12:43 nginx.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          4 Aug 10 11:50 rsyslogd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root         60 Aug 10 11:53 samba
drwx--x---  2 root          sasl        140 Aug 10 11:50 saslauthd
drwxrwxr-x  2 root          utmp         40 Aug 10 11:50 screen
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root         40 Aug 10 11:50 sendsigs.omit.d
drwxrwxrwt  2 root          root         40 Aug 10 11:50 shm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root         40 Aug 10 11:50 sshd
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          4 Aug 10 11:51 sshd.pid
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root        100 Aug 11 11:12 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root        100 Aug 10 11:53 udev
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          5 Aug 10 11:53 upstart-file-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          5 Aug 10 11:53 upstart-socket-bridge.pid
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          5 Aug 10 11:53 upstart-udev-bridge.pid
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root         40 Sep  8 12:16 user
-rw-rw-r--  1 root          utmp       1.5K Sep  8 12:15 utmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root          root          6 Sep  8 12:28 xinetd.pid
```

`php5-fpm -t` displays the following:

```
$ php5-fpm -t
Mon Sep  8 13:11:04 2014 (27954): Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)
```

`php5-fpm` is not running:

```
$ ps -ef                                                                                                                     2 ↵
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:13 init
root         2     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd/781170]
root         3     2  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 [khelper/7811702]
syslog     348     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:45 rsyslogd
root       390     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:04 cron
root       577     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
root       578   577  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 2
root       869     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:33 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
mysql     3906     1  0 Sep01 ?        00:09:05 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      8416     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
root      8472     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
root      8474     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
root      8477     1  0 Aug10 ?        00:00:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
message+ 14085     1  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
root     14142     1  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
avahi    14263     1  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [server2.local]
avahi    14265 14263  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root     18283   869  0 11:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: belstgut [priv]
belstgut 18294 18283  0 11:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: belstgut@pts/0
belstgut 18295 18294  0 11:49 pts/0    00:00:03 -zsh
root     19303 18295  0 11:56 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo -s
root     19304 19303  0 11:56 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/bin/zsh
root     24237     1  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid -stayalive -inetd_compat -inetd_ipv6
root     24395     1  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/master
postfix  24398 24395  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 pickup -l -t unix -u -c
postfix  24399 24395  0 12:28 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
root     25052     1  0 12:43 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 25055 25052  0 12:43 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 25056 25052  0 12:43 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 25057 25052  0 12:43 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 25058 25052  0 12:43 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     28039   869  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: unknown [priv]
sshd     28040 28039  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: unknown [net]
root     28084   869  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [accepted]
sshd     28085 28084  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [net]
root     28086   869  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [accepted]
sshd     28087 28086  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [net]
root     28088   869  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [accepted]
sshd     28089 28088  0 13:12 ?        00:00:00 sshd: [net]
root     28126 19304  0 13:13 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you using APC? If you are, you could try increasing apc memory size: `apc.shm_size=96M` and check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/what-is-causing-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-pool-in-php

Comment: already read about apc. i disabled it for the moment. still same error

Comment: ok odd: i removed apc with apt-get remove php-apc and pecl uninstall apcu

but it was still enabled in mods-available/apcu.ini commenting this out worked.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest removing APC. Have you tried increasing `shm_size`?