# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start()

Tags: php, session, exception, zend-framework, zend-session

This is a screenshot with the error dump: [image: any idea what can be caused of this?]

I occassionaly get this error while browsing a website i am developing. Obviously session can't be started but i have no idea how to prevent this error because it occurs randomly (as it seems to me). Any idea how can I prevent this error to occur?

Comment: Please post some bootstrap code and your `configs/application.ini`, at least the parts relevant to session handling.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930870/zend-session-zend-auth-randomly-throws-error-message-ps-files-cleanup-dir-ope

Comment: What is happening is that PHP is trying to do garbage collection on the session files, and for some reason the executing process doesn't have permission to manipulate the directory `/var/lib/php5`.  If session GC is going to be initiated, it happens when you call session_start.  See Liyali's link for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and found the root case that PHP application was developed using PHP 5.6. Later on, I installed PHP 7.2 & trying to run PHP 5.6 application using PHP 7.2. Disabling PHP 7.2 worked for me.

Sharing below commands for reference:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 
sudo a2enmod php5.6 
sudo service apache2 restart 
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6 
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6 
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6
```